# How do I include other columns in the results of a Google Sheets GROUP BY COUNT() query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Suppose I have a Google spreadsheet (`Sheet1`) with columns `A:L`. In another sheet (`Sheet2`) I want to aggregate data from `Sheet1` as follows:

- The only relevant columns in `Sheet1` are `D, G, H, J, K`.
- I want to `GROUP BY J`, `SORT BY COUNT(J)` and return columns `D, G, H, J, K, COUNT(J)` in descending order by `COUNT(J)`.

I can get this to work when using only one column:

```
=QUERY('Sheet1'!J2:J,"select J, count(J) where J is not null group by J order by count(J) DESC label count(J) ''")
```

But I can't figure out how to make it also return columns `D, G, H, K` as well.

It's important to note that any rows that share a value at column J will share values at all of the other relevant columns in those rows.

Here is a link to a [Google Sheet with sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xaa4KQnTyJn6CLvhh3WADANYwSPweNKAq-9Ki4lIzNw/edit). Notice the formula in cell `A2` of `Sheet2`.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: @rockinfreakshow Thank you for this. I posted a link to a sheet with sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```cpp
=QUERY('Sheet1'!D2:J,
       "select D, G, H, K, J, count(J)
        where J is not null
        group by D, G, H, K, J
        order by count(J) DESC label count(J) ''")
```

Comment: This is very close, but I'm not getting all of the counts to match the results of my original formula, which I know was correct. This means there's something in my data that I'm not aware of. I can't share the data, and I can't anonymize the whole sheet. It seems like this is a good start though. Thanks!

Comment: can you manually enter the desired result in the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xaa4KQnTyJn6CLvhh3WADANYwSPweNKAq-9Ki4lIzNw/edit?usp=drivesdk) you've shared?

Comment: @z.. The OP isn't saying that the result from the sample data is wrong.  They are saying that, when applied to their actual data, the outcome is inconsistent with expectations... AND they can't/won't share their live data. I think they have a piece of trouble-shooting to do.